# Does Heine-Cantor theorem holds for functions of several variables?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that Heine-Cantor theorem holds for functions of single variable and says that a continuous function between two metric spaces is uniformly continuous and that it is used for proving that any continuous function is integrable, but I have seen that same argument used to prove integrability of continuous functions of several variables but haven't seen any proof of Heine-Cantor theorem for functions of several variables or a statement that it holds.

So my question is does it hold and if it does where can I find proof of that and if it doesn't does the argument used for proving integrability for functions of several variables come from some other property of continuous functions of several variables?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/403823/57159 $\;$

Comment: I don't understand does the function act as a product of two spaces or are different compact spaces represent spaces for different variables and their product is domain of function? @Ricky_Demer

Comment: "a continuous function between two metric spaces is uniformly continuous" Nope. Sometimes yes, but no in general.

Comment: The general statement can actully be found in the wiki page. That covers the several variables case as it is on a general metric space.